# Distributed BlockMatrix out of Spark Matrices

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

> How to make a distributed `BlockMatrix` out of `Matrices` (of the same size)?

For example, let A, B be two 2 by 2 mllib.linalg.Matrices as follows

```scala
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Matrix, Matrices}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.BlockMatrix

val A: Matrix = Matrices.dense(2, 2, Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0))
val B: Matrix = Matrices.dense(2, 2, Array(5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0))
val C = new BlockMatrix(???)
```

How can I first make an `RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)]` from A, B and second a distributed `BlockMatrix` out of A, B?

I'd appreciate any comment or help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can construct the `BlockMatrix` by first creating the `RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)]`

```scala
val blocks: RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)] = sc.parallelize(Seq(((0, 0), A), ((0, 1), B))
```

and then converting it into a `BlockMatrix`.

```scala
val blockMatrix: BlockMatrix = new BlockMatrix(blocks, 2, 2)
```

This will give you a `BlockMatrix`, which has the form `[A | B]`.

Comment: Right! so I need to `import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD` first and define the type of blocks. I was just using the `sc.parallelize` and it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get a particular block ( block i,j) from blockMatrix above?

Comment: You can do this by accessing the underlying blocks `RDD`. E.g. `blockMatrix.blocks.filter{case ((x, y), matrix) => x == i && y == j}` will give you an `RDD[((Int, Int), Matrix)]` with only the selected block in it.